# Can't configure SDK after installation of Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk

So I got my new laptop(Win 10) and installed the Android studio 2.2.3 with SDK bundle. 
When I first executed Android Studio it got stuck on the splash screen. adding "Add disable.android.first.run=true" to the idea.properties file solved it.

After I got to the first screen, I needed to configure SDK in order to create new project so I clicked on Configure->Project Defaults -> project structure.
I set the location of the SDK and JDK , and then it gets stuck with the "Checking Availability" message:
[Checking Availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRLAA.png)

I also tried to configure the sdk by clicking from the first screen on
Configure -> SDK Manager.
In this screen it also gets stuck with the message :Looking for updates":
[Looking for updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YFhf.png)

I tried to install it as Administrator and also to install lower version.
It didn't help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all update Android Studio to [latest version(V2.3.1)](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) with complete bundle.
Then you don't need to install jdk manually. after finish installation check "Use embedded jdk" in project structure if not checked. and if you needed Android NDK kit then you can download it later.